# I have created a web application using (Spring Boot + Thymeleaf)

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

my problem is to show 2 different images including the data value from database using Thymeleaf
[here is the UI exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIdLh.png).

I need to show the **espece.png** when the Payment was **"espece"** and show the **check.png** when the Payment was **"par check"**

HTML:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4" th:each="projets : ${listeProjets}">
         <div class="card border border-primary">
          <div class="card-header bg-transparent border-primary d-flex align-items-start">
            <h5 class="my-0 text-primary" th:text="${projets.nomProjet}"></h5>
             <div class="flex-shrink-0 ms-2"> 
               <img class="card-img-top" alt="" src="/assets/images/tache/espece.png" width="40" height="40" />
          </div>
    <div class="flex-shrink-0 ms-2">
        <a href=""><i class="bx bx-x font-size-20"></i></a>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">card title</h5>
            <div class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated bg-success"
                    role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" 
                    th:style="'width:'+${projets.avancement}+';'" th:text="${projets.avancement}"> 
                </div>
            </div>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer bg-transparent border-primary">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light waves-effect w-100" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#addModal">
    <i class="bx bx-plus font-size-16 align-middle"></i>Ajouter Tâche
    </button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Java class:

```java
    @Entity
    public class Projet {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int id;
        @Column(nullable = false, length = 25)
        private String nomProjet;
        @Column(length = 100)
        private String description;
        private Date dateDebut;
        private Date dateFin;
        private float prix;
        @Column(length = 15)
        private String methodePaiement;
        @Column(length = 10)
        private String avancement;
    
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "clientid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
        private Client client;
        private int clientid;
    
        /** Default Constructor, getters and setters **/ 
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img class="card-img-top" alt="" th:with="paymentImageName = ${projets.methodePaiement == 'espece'}? 'espece' : 'check'" th:src="@{/assets/images/tache/{imageName}.png(imageName=${paymentImageName})}" width="40" height="40" />
```

1. By using [the:with](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#local-variables), I have introduced the local variable `paymentImageName` where set the appropriate name according to [conditional expression](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#conditional-expressions).
2. Used [link URL](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls) to process the image URL with appropriate image name, set in step #1 and parsed already  by Thymeleaf according to [Attribute Precedence](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#attribute-precedence)
3. Read more on [Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html)